# Hierarchical modeling in R

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

Here i am again. From this script:

```
model1 <- zelig(Decision ~ as.factor(age) + as.factor(income) + as.factor(town.type) +
                tag(town.type|town), model="logit.mixed", data=Fish)
```

Does it mean that `town.type` is treated both as fixed effects and random effects and `town` treated as random effects nested in `town.type`?

I am currently analyzing the effects of `age` and `income` to the decision of fishers to exit the fishery. In addition i added `town.type` (whether the respondent comes from developed (coded 2) or less developed (coded 1) towns ) as fixed effects. We surveyed many towns each of which we categorized into one of two town types.

I'm sorry, i am new to R. Hope you could help me out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ Richard Muallil Your grouping variable is `town` (level 2), right? `town.type` is a level 2 predictor. Does it make sense to model `town.type` as a random slope `tag(town.type|town)`?

Comment: @Richard Muallil Zelig comes with some potentially useful documentation. Mixed-effects logit model specification is described in this document: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Zelig/vignettes/logit.mixed.pdf